# Setting opacity/filter of a div in IE5+

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, html, filter, opacity

Yes I've seen tons of posts online about this question but I can't seem to get my opacity to work in Internet Explorer 5+ using.

```
var container_div = document.getElementById(id);       
var container_filter = 0;
container_div.style.filter = container_filter;
```

This does work in all the other standard browsers.

```
var container_div = document.getElementById(id);       
var container_opacity = 0;
container_div.style.opacity = container_opacity;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE5? *Seriously*???

Anyway, the short answer is that IE's `filter` style is a lot more complex than that because it deals with many different effects. You need to set the whole filter string, not just an integer value.

The syntax is quite complex, and not very easy to work with in Javascript. The results can be a bit hit-and-miss too; it doesn't always work very well, even when you do get it right.

Rather than try to tell you how to make the `filter` work, I'll point you to a third party Javascript library that might make things easier: [cssSandpaper](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/csssandpaper-a-css3-javascript-library/).

cssSandpaper is a JS library that implements several modern CSS features into old versions of IE.

You can then use CSS to set your opacity for IE like this:

```
opacity: 0.3;
```

...or Javascript like this:

```
cssSandpaper.setOpacity(container_div, 0.3);
```

Both these examples are as per the documentation on the page I linked above.

Note: I doubt very much whether this library will work with IE5, but frankly, don't let that worry you. It's considered a waste of time for most people to even support IE6 these days.

Comment: I know IE5 is older than windows xp but I did say ie5+. I'm still on XP!

Comment: Why would you want opacity in IE5? If you are forced to code to a browser that old, you should probably stick to features that are well supported by it. No reason a site needs to look the same in all browsers, just in all recent browsers, no harm in having a fallback for older stuff.

Comment: I guess the ultimate question is; Why does internet explorer suck so bad? and why can't they implement the standards most browsers have?

Comment: @lost_with_coding - they *have* implemented modern standards. IE9 is pretty good, and IE10 is right there with the rest of them. Okay, so neither of those versions work in WinXP, but how old is XP? If you had a MacOS version that old, you would also have a very old browser that you couldn't upgrade. Companies still on XP need to switch now, because the last little bits of support will end early next year. And home users: frankly, I can't understand anyone still using XP. You can get better performance and better compatibility by installing Linux and using Wine to run Windows apps.

Comment: @spudley, maybe more recent windows apps for windows 8 but when it comes to games made for 98-Xp chances are they wont even work on Vista and there are tons of PC games still worth playing from that era.

Comment: @lost_with_coding - that's what a virtual machine is for. And Win8 comes with a built-in XP mode. But also, I think you'd be surprised how well Linux with Wine works with old WinXP games. But anyway, we're getting off topic now. Back to browsers, even XP can run IE8, so there's no good reason for anyone to be using a version older than that. IE8 may not be that good, but it's not *that* bad. And if XP users want something better, there's always Firefox or Chrome.

Comment: I started a more specific thread regarding opacity and cssSandpaper(). please HELP! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15123957/csssandpaper-setopacitynode-0-does-not-work