# cssSandpaper.setOpacity(node,0) does not work?

Tags: javascript, css, dom, opacity

This is what I have so far for setting the opacity for an image. Using `container_div.style.opacity() = 0` instead of `cssSandpaper.setOpacity(container_div,0)` works for every browser besides IE, but I wanted it to work on IE too so I used cssSandpaper.

```
var image_tag;

image_tag = document.createElement("img");  
image_tag.setAttribute("height", "100%");
image_tag.setAttribute("width", "100%");
image_tag.src = "image.png"     
document.getElementById(id).appendChild(image_tag); 

var container_div = document.getElementById(id);  
cssSandpaper.setOpacity(container_div, 0);
```